# Compiled mono missing default .NET libraries - System.Object is not defined or imported

Tags: c#, macos, mono, xbuild

I've compiled mono on OS X Mavericks following the guide located here: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/compiling-mono/mac/

Now when I compile my application using xbuild I'm getting the following errors:

```
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Object' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.ValueType' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Attribute' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Int32' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.UInt32' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Int64' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.UInt64' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Single' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Double' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Char' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Int16' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Decimal' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Boolean' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.SByte' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Byte' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.UInt16' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.String' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Enum' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Delegate' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.MulticastDelegate' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Void' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Array' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Type' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Collections.IEnumerator' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Collections.IEnumerable' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.IDisposable' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.IntPtr' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.UIntPtr' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.RuntimeFieldHandle' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.RuntimeTypeHandle' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Exception' is not defined or imported
```

When I used the mono installer on OS X I never received any of these errors.

(I'm building mono because I'm adding functionality to the .NET framework that wasn't completed)

Result of running autogen.sh: https://gist.github.com/Geesu/149332f3f877c891d387
Result of running make: https://gist.github.com/Geesu/4296f7d4c6c368d6986d

Comment: Can you post the actual csc line, and locations of it and the built libraries?

Comment: How can I provide this? I'm not sure how to find the CSC line.  Also, I can post the output of the compilation - would that help?

Comment: I've added the result of autogen.sh and make above

Comment: Are those results for building mono, or your app?

Comment: The gists are of building mono.

Comment: Could you post a gist of the entire xbuild output?

Answer (score 13):

If there is a warning similar to:

```
/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Unable to find framework corresponding to the target framework moniker '.NETFramework,Version=v2.0'. Framework assembly references will be resolved from the GAC, which might not be the intended behavior.
```

You can override the .NET Framework on the command line:

```
xbuild /p:TargetFrameworkVersion="v4.0"
```

You can change your solution:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this issue while building YouCompleteMe / OmniSharpServer on Debian unstable (Sid).  What's happening is the installed version of mono doesn't have the v4.5.2 Framework assemblies installed, which is what the compiler defaults to when building that solution/project.

Workaround is to specify the targeted framework version as one you have available, or make available the one being targeted (e.g. during your custom compilation).

Cat Zimmermann's response is apt.

Answer (score 3):

I stumpled acros this problem to. I forgot to check for updates after rerunning the Mavericks installer, and there were Stable channel updates available for both Mono and Xamarin.Android. Once I installed them, everything built just fine.

Comment: The original poster is talking about a mono installation that is compiled from scratch, not downloaded via Xamarin, or through the mono installer.

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting bin and obj folders in all projects of that solution. 
Seems like those folders were having old files generated by some older version of visual studio, which are not compatible with new version of visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

The difference with the installer and the home build is the fact that the installer "knows" where the libarys are located, whereas the compiled one dont. So unless you point to that location when compiling your app, your problem will occure (there are basically no system dll's found). I would recommend looking into [the mcs documentation](http://mono.wikia.com/wiki/Man_mcs) , and specify the path. (EDIT: with the "-L "  parameter should do it.).

Comment: I wouldn't need the mcs tool.  I'm trying to compile mono itself.  I'm adding functionality to it that hasn't been completed.

Answer (score 1):

my project started compiling, when I removed lines

```
<NoStdLib>true</NoStdLib>
<NoConfig>true</NoConfig>
```

from it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to back this logically, but after trying to fix this for couple of hours,

```
Unload .net standards project
```

because I was not getting the exact problem and decided to

```
reload it again
```

boom... It worked... still don't know what is the logical reason behind it. if someone does, please comment below.

Comment: weird, but it worked ! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by change the project setting->general->Target Framework to Mono/.NET 4.5.

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I checked my Target Framework
Path: `Properties>Aplication:Target Framework` and set it to `.Net Framework 4.7`.